# Multi-node secured Cockroach Db cluster with docker

Tags: docker, certificate, cockroachdb

I have been able to create a single node insecure cluster using below docker command:

```
docker run -d --name cockroach -p 26257:26257 -p 8080:8080 <my_artifactory>/cockroachdb/cockroach:v20.1.6 start-single-node --insecure
```

I have also been able to create a multi node insecure cluster using below command:

```
docker run -d --name=roach1 --hostname=roach1 --net=roachnet -p 26257:26257 -p 8080:8080 <my_artifactory>/cockroachdb/cockroach:v20.1.6 start --insecure --join=roach1,roach2,roach3

docker run -d --name=roach2 --hostname=roach2 --net=roachnet <my_artifactory>/cockroachdb/cockroach:v20.1.6 start --insecure --join=roach1,roach2,roach3

docker run -d --name=roach3 --hostname=roach3 --net=roachnet <my_artifactory>/cockroachdb/cockroach:v20.1.6 start --insecure --join=roach1,roach2,roach3
```

Now I'm tryint to bring up a multi-node secured cluster. I have followed all the commands on these pages :

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.2/create-security-certificates-openssl#step-1-create-the-ca-key-and-certificate-pair

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.2/create-security-certificates-openssl#step-2-create-the-certificate-and-key-pairs-for-nodes

Now I'm trying to bring up the cluster as below:

```
docker run --name=roach1 --hostname=roach1 --net=roachnet -p 26257:26257 -p 8080:8080 <my_artifactory>/cockroachdb/cockroach:v20.1.6 start --certs-dir=certs --join=roach1,roach2,roach3
```

I am in the directory wherein the 'certs' subdirectory exists. But I am getting the below error:

```
    * ERROR: ERROR: cannot load certificates.
* Check your certificate settings, set --certs-dir, or use --insecure for insecure clusters.
*
* failed to start server: problem with CA certificate: not found
*
ERROR: cannot load certificates.
Check your certificate settings, set --certs-dir, or use --insecure for insecure clusters.

failed to start server: problem with CA certificate: not found
Failed running "start"
```

I am not sure what is the issue.

Comment: Have you copied the certs directory from the host file system to the filesystem of each container? There are a number of ways to do to this, including the `COPY` command in a Dockerfile, `docker cp src container:/dest`, or mounting a volume with the `-v` flag in `docker run`: `docker run --name=roach1 --hostname=roach1 --net=roachnet -p 26257:26257 -p 8080:8080 <my_artifactory>/cockroachdb/cockroach:v20.1.6 start --certs-dir=certs --join=roach1,roach2,roach3 -v /path/to/host/certs:/certs`.